# Filtering rows pro-grammatically in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am currently displaying data in a table in my angular 4 application and applied stying. I have implemented
styling by creating the fields to be highlighted in the config file and looping through those rows and highlighting

Table

[image]

**html code**

```
 <!-- Income table -->
            <div *ngIf="selectedFinancialOption===1 && fsIncomeStatementTable && fsIncomeStatementTable.length > 0" class="tab-pane fade active show" id="base-strategy--fs-statement" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="height:50px">
                            <th *ngFor="let cell of fsIncomeStatementTable[0]"> {{cell}}</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[0] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[1] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[2] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[3]}">
                            <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                            <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1">{{cell | shortAndBlankNumberFormat: 2}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <!-- Income table -->
```

**Config Code**

```
    export const CONSTS: any = {

results: {

    financialStatement: {
        //TO DO SORT THIS OUT - Used for Styling
        incomeStatementStyling: 'Net premiums written|AY Underwriting Gain|Net Investment income|Net Operating Income|Net Income',
        cashFlowStyling: 'Net Cash provided by operating activities|Cash and Investments, end of year',
        balanceSheetStyling: 'Total Cash and Investment|Total Assets|Total Liabilites|Total Liabilities Total Sh. Equity'
    }
}
}
```

**Angular component**

```
    const incomeStatementStyling: string[] = String(CONSTS.results.financialStatement.incomeStatementStyling).split('|');

    export class FinancialStatementComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
      isExpanded = false;

      incomeStatementStyles: string[] = incomeStatementStyling;

      constructor(private _projectionService: ProjectionService) {
    super();
  }

  @Input() set fsResult(value: FinancialStatementAnalysis) {
    this.processFSResults(value);
  }

   processFSResults(value: FinancialStatementAnalysis) {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    this._fsIncomeStatementTable = this._projectionService.fsIncomeStatementResults(value.incomeStatement);

  }

      }
```

I need to now filter certain rows. How do I handle that bit ? Is it in the config or do i do it at the component level ?

Answer (score 0):

To filter Data in Angular, you simply do:

```
this.filteredData = this.Data.filter((item) => item.Name.toUpperCase() === this.otherData.Name.toUpperCase());
```

More on that [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I am trying to filter the property of the object here. value is of the type FinancialStatement Analysis which contains object IncomeStatement having property DefferedTaxAssets which i need to filter. How do i do that

Comment: I was trying something like this but getting sytax error  
  let filteredCashFlow = ['deferredTaxAssets']; 
 this._filteredCashFlowTable = filteredCashFlow.filter((item) => item.toUpperCase() === value.incomeStatement.deferredTaxAssets.);

Comment: @Tom  As stated at the link I posted above ina an answer, the filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. To filter your `filteredCashFlow` by Name for instance, you will write: `this._filteredCashFlowTable = filteredCashFlow.filter((item) => item.Name.toUpperCase() === value.incomeStatement.deferredTaxAssets.); `

Comment: it shows a red squigly under item.Name. It doesnt recognise name as property

Comment: @Tom "Name" was just for example. If you tell me by which data you would like to filter, maybe I can help more.

Comment: I basically want deferredTaxAssets to be filtered from the list

Comment: I have initialied the filtered list as let filteredCashFlow = ['deferredTaxAssets'] as any;

Comment: @Tom where is deferredTaxAssets in your data? What is column name in your Database or in your array where deferredTaxAssets is?

Comment: @Tom Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172157/discussion-between-joe-belladonna-and-tom).

Comment: Hi Joe, I have resolved the issue by not adding the relevant items into the array in my service class and pass that array to the client. It was relatively easier that manipulating it on the client

Comment: @Tom I'm glad to hear you have managed to solve your issue. :-)